# How to display widgets in subclass of QAbstractItemView?

Tags: c++, qt, qabstractitemview

I want to display contents of a data model customly, that is, display every row of the model using a widget.

I have subclassed `QAbstractItemView` and tried to display widgets by creating a layout, asigning it to the viewport and then adding items to it. I have performed widget creation in appropriate slots (`reset()`, `rowsInserted`), but in the end nothing is displayed despite layout having items in it.

How can i ensure my widgets are displayed in the viewport? Must they be set using `setIndexWidget()` instead?

Comment: 1. You don't need to subclass `QAbstractItemView`. I didn't see any real projects, that implements their own views. 2. You don't need to use widgets to display data. Instead of it you should try to implement your own `QItemDelegate`.

Comment: Implementing `QItemDelegate` that displays data the way i want it would be too much hassle. It is best suited for cases where data can be split by roles  for the same index.

Comment: As you wish... You still may use `setIndexWidget` but it will work very slow for large amount of items.